# How to identify which image belongs to which person after uploading excel sheet (exceljs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, exceljs

When I put the same picture in Excel for different rows and try to get it in React using the following,

```
workbook.getImage(image.imageId)
```

I notice that even if the pictures are in different rows, I always get the same numbers for 'nativeRow' and 'imageId'. How to identify which image belongs to which row or which person in exceljs?

[image]

Is there any other way I can follow to achieve the same?